# Repeat events on selected days in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

How i can create repeating events on selected days, for example in monday and tuesday.
My event enter code here array data from json:

```
"title": "Test",
"allDay": false,
"start": "2014-12-11 9:30:00",
"end": "2014-12-11 13:00:00",
"repeat": '1,2,3', // first 3 days of week
```

How i can do this?
I want show only on calendar repeating, becouse repeating is save i database.
I must create repeating events on selected days, i have problem with this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You should create your events as different events, with same Id.

From [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

> id     String/Integer. Optional
>
> Uniquely identifies the given event. Different instances of **repeating
>   events** should all have the same id.

So your events should be like:

```
myevents = [
   {
      "id":1
      "title": "Test",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2014-12-12 9:30:00",
      "end": "2014-12-12 13:00:00"
   },
   {
      "id":1
      "title": "Test",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2014-12-13 9:30:00",
      "end": "2014-12-13 13:00:00"
   },
   {
      "id":1
      "title": "Test",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2014-12-14 9:30:00",
      "end": "2014-12-14 13:00:00"
   }
]
```