# Add repeating events to weekdays on FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am creating a timetable using MVC and FullCalendar (fullcalendar.io/), and typically adding an "event" to the calendar would look like the following:

```
{
     id: 999,
     title: 'This is the class type',
     start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00',
     end: '2015-02-09T17:00:00',
     room: 'This is the room number',
     module: 'This is the module name'
},
```

However I would like to be able to enter a weekday in the "start" and "end" parameters rather than a date, and have this event occur every week on the same day. Would this be possible?

Comment: what you ask is not possible; you have to create one event for each day. keep the id the same if you want to 'link' them, but the 'start' and 'end' has to change to reflect each day of the week you want it displayed.  momentjs has easy ways to do this, or via your backend system.

Comment: Please, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375870/repeat-events-on-selected-days-in-fullcalendar/27383018#27383018

Comment: I've edited your question to include the word "repeating" since that is what we usually call this kind of event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullcalendar doesn't directly support this but that doesn't mean it isn't possible, you just need to be creative.

Essentially, we are going loop through the visible days, testing each for a match to our rule. We can do this with an event source since [they can be defined as functions](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/Loun6r4v/)

```
// Returns all the days between two dates that pass the test function
var matchingDaysBetween = function (start, end, test) {
    var days = [];
    for (var day = moment(start); day.isBefore(end); day.add(1, 'd')) {
        if (test(day)) {
            days.push(moment(day)); // push a copy of day
        }
    }
    return days;
}

$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    // Fullcalendar will load sources defined here every view change.
    eventSources: [{
        // Every sunday as a background event
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { 
            // Get the days
            var days = matchingDaysBetween(start, end, function (day) {
                return day.format('dddd') === 'Sunday'; //test function
            });

            // Map days to events
            callback(days.map(function (day) { 
                return {
                    start: moment(day).startOf('day'),
                    end: moment(day).endOf('day'),
                    title: "sunday",
                    rendering: 'background',
                    id: "sundays"
                };
            }));
        }
    }, {
        // Every tuesday noon to 2pm
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var days = matchingDaysBetween(start, end, function (day) {
                return day.format('dddd') === 'Tuesday'; //test function
            });
            callback(days.map(function (day) { // map days to events
                return {
                    start: moment(day).hour(12),
                    end: moment(day).hour(14),
                    title: "lunch",
                    id: "tueslunch"
                };
            }));
        }
    }]
});
```

That should be easy enough to customize to fit most simple use cases.